# Wordpress stripping youtube embed tags in post

Tags: php, html, wordpress, youtube

I am trying to insert this video into my Wordpress post:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/5CvLs2KCAEc" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I know Wordpress does not allow embedding of videos for security reasons, so you use the short code: [embed width="123" height="456"]...[/embed] (replacing the periods with the url) But for some reason this also is not working..

I am using the Reventon theme if that helps at all..

Comment: Try posting that here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If wordpress doesn't allow it, why are you trying to circumvent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress [supports automatic embedding](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) from certain sites, including YouTube.  Simply add the YouTube video's URL to your post content, and WordPress will automatically create the embed for you.